# TFS - Merge code from two versions of same file ( in same branch )

Tags: tfs, merge, changeset

I have Two change sets in TFS (for a single file) , for example 8901 and 9053.

I want to merge the code in both these change sets.

[image: The Image contains all the change sets]

When I select both the change sets, I don't find any option except compare and copy. Please refer below screenshot of the same.

[image]

I want to merge these two changesets so that I the file will finally contain both the versions of code.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this? Please help.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merge is using between branches, not between changesets.

It seems 9053 is the latest version of your project, so you should have get this version in your workspace. In my example, it's `TestCaseProject`.

Then you can try to create a branch for this project from 8901, named `TestCaseProject-branch`:

[image]

After that, perform a merge from `TestCaseProject` to `TestCaseProject-branch`, and you can check whether TestCaseProject-branch includes all changes you need in 8901 and 9053.

Comment: Thank You for your response. I have a changeset 8901. Code in that change set had to be reverted and checked in as changeset 8962. After multiple checkins up to 9053, I now want to get the code of 8901 as well. Could you please suggest if this is possible? As per your suggestion, I created a new branch but it reflects only the last checkedin version.